# Infer up from age metric

Tags: prometheus

I'm trying to display an Availability Gauge of a service I do not own and which does not expose the `up` metric.

However it does expose a metric for the age of the service (how long is it running).
I was wondering if it would be possible to infer an `up` metric, ranging from [0, 1] that indicates whether the service is up or not.

Thanks!

Comment: The `up` metric is generated by Prometheus. What do you mean by `does not expose` it ?

Comment: From the prometheus docs, `up` is 1 if the target was successfully scraped or `0` otherwise. If you're scraping the service with prometheus you should have an up metric.